# How to set custom post type as parent of page?

Tags: wordpress

I've found plenty of info on how to set a page as the parent of a custom post type, but not the other way round - I want to set a custom post type as the parent of my page.

I've found the following hook, originally intended to add drafts to the list of available parents for a page. It works for adding drafts, but if I use it to chaneg the retrieved post type, the parent pulldown on the page edit screen disappears. Any ideas?

```
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'so_3538267_enable_drafts_parents' );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'so_3538267_enable_drafts_parents' );

function so_3538267_enable_drafts_parents( $args )
{
//$args['post_status'] = 'draft,publish,pending';//works
$args['post_type'] = 'campaign';//custom post type name - doesn't work
return $args;
}
```

---

I've got it working. The code above is good, I just needed to set my custom post type to be hierarchical.

Edit:
I spoke too soon. The above change allowed me to select the custom post type as the parent of the page, but now the child page is inaccessible on the frontend. I get a 404 error. I've tried flushing permalinks as usual.

The URL it's trying to use for the page:
http://www.example.com/sample-campaign-6/about-campaign/

the first part is the slug for the parent custom post type.

Can anyone tell me how to get this working?

Thanks.